# SVN to Git Migration - Using one trunk with multiple projects

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I have a single SVN repository with the below structure where I am interested in seven projects out of 20+.

- Branches

  - Project1
  - Project2
  - Project3
  - Project4
  - Project...
- Releases

  - Project1
  - Project3
  - Project...
- Tags

  - Project1
  - Project2
  - Project3
  - Project4
  - Project5
  - Project6
  - Project7
  - Project...
- Trunk

  - Project1
  - Project2
  - Project3
  - Project4
  - Project5
  - Project6
  - Project7
  - Project...

I have tried following [the migration guide from Bitbucket](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/migrating-convert) with additions found through other posts. No matter which of the below commands I try I end up with an empty .git repository.

How would I manage to only get one project out into a git repository using git svn?

**Commands tried**

`git svn clone –std-layout –authors-file=authors.txt http://{companyURL}/{teamName}/trunk/Project4 Project4`

`git svn clone –trunk=/trunk –branches=/branches –tags=/tags –authors-file=authors.txt http://{companyURL}/{teamName}/trunk/Project4 Project4`

`git svn clone –trunk=/trunk –branches=/branches –tags=/tags –authors-file=authors.txt http://{companyURL}/{teamName}/trunk/Project4 Project4 --no-minimize-url`

`git svn clone  –trunk=/trunk/NemloginIntegration –branches=/branches/NemloginIntegration –tags=/tags/NemloginIntegration –authors-file=authors.txt http://{companyURL}/{teamName}/trunk/Project4 Project4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing as this guide from Dan Santos: [Migrating-subversion-to-git](https://www.219design.com/migrating-subversion-to-git/)

Example using my above scenario:

```
git svn clone --prefix="" --trunk=/trunk/project4/ --branches=/branches/project4 --tags=/tags/project4 --authors-file=authors.txt http://{companyURL}/{teamName} Project4AsGit --no-minimize-url
```

The different part here is the URL I use for Repo is still on a parent level, and only branches, tags, and the trunk is drilled down to the correct position. --no-minimize-url is making sure git is not going away from these drilled down URLs.

The next thing Dan mentions is to use '--prefix=""', as this will make the below clean-git command works as expected. I did try without which ended up with me not having SVN tags become git tags.

```
java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar svn-migration-scripts.jar clean-git
```